# How to downgrade from Android 9 to Android 8 or Android 7 on LG V20?

Tags: 9.0-pie, lg

I am using LG V20, model number is LG-F800K. 2 days ago, I installed the official update to Android 9. However after the update, my phone became battery drained faster and worked slower than before. I have tried at least the following 3 ways to try to get back to Android 7 or Android 8:

1. https://forum.xda-developers.com/v20/how-to/guide-lg-v20-to-life-t3827732 -> "Download failed" error.
2. https://lg-firmwares.com/how-to-flash/#how-to-flash-new -> Unknown model.
3. https://lg-firmwares.com/how-to-flash/#how-to-flash-old -> Error "could not connect to server".

As of now, I really don't know how to reduce the Android version on this device?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: afaik unlocking bootloader will let you by-pass anti rollback protection, but this requires a factory reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downgraded the version successfully. You need to use LGUP DualMode in this case, it will help identify your device!

You can download it here (Copyright © by TecKnight): [LGUP_DualMode.zip](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=11410963190603845019)

Comment: What is your connection to this download? Are you the developer, creator, or owner for it? Should there be a disclaimer of personal interest here?

Comment: @wbogacz It works on computers, you just need to plug your phone, via USB cable into download mode, it is recoverable.
That software was given to me by a foreign friend who works at an LG store, I added copyright information based on the upload account name because I didn't know exactly who was the owner of it.